# FTP server stuck with arabic file names

Tags: vba, utf-8, ftp

I'm writing a VBA code that makes Ms Access DB put and get files on/to an FTP server runs in win server 2012 R2 IIS and allows UTF-8.

The FTP server accepts files from it's local Machine with Arabic file names with no problems, but hangs when try the same from another computer running win 7 or win 8,

I got a code from the internet to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 using WideCharToMultiByte function but it's not working, returns question marks..

Any advice?

Comment: So the problem is not with the FTP server, but with the conversion using `WideCharToMultiByte`, correct? Show us the conversion code, show us the input and the output (ideally a hex dump of a small example).

Comment: I have this idea that Arabic file names should go through encoding and decoding process, I was encoding the file name and have a bytes array using the function WideCharToMultiByte, and forgut to use the second part which is the decoding using another function MultiByteToWideChar, unfortunately after doing so, I can see that the file name is correct in the immediate window in the vba console but the problem stills, I'm passing this decoded string to a shell command to transport the file to the ftp, and after the "Port open successfully" nothing happen!